# Arrange multiple (32) .png files in a grid

Tags: r, png, grid-layout

I've been pulling my hair out for the past week trying to figure out elementary R coding but can't seem to get anywhere (haven't used R since 2013 not that its a great excuse).

All I want is a **4x8 grid made up of 32 .png files** (maps I've made), and I want to do it without loading one image file at a time (http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html).

So I think I can load the images within the folder writing (please correct me if my beliefs are bs)

```
img <- list.files(path='c:/a',patt='compo[0-32].*',full.names=T)
```

Then I was thinking maybe in the lines of  `par(mfrow=c())`, `layout`, `grid.arrange` ([writing png plots into a pdf file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852395/writing-png-plots-into-a-pdf-file-in-r)), `grid.raster` ([How to join efficiently multiple rgl plots into one single plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221988/how-to-join-efficiently-multiple-rgl-plots-into-one-single-plot)) - which I've read up on and experimented with accordingly not resulting in anything worthwhile..

The latter I employed only with the following outcome [image]

It made me giggle.
I don't really think `lattice` is the way to go anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't read like you should use R for this. With your problem description I would probably use ImageMagick: http://superuser.com/a/290679

Comment: You could use the raster package to read them as bricks or stacks and then cbind/rbind them together into one big image...

Comment: this answer does the thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108620/3315869

Answer (score 15):

Another approach is to read the PNG images with readPNG then use grid and gridExtra:

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot1 <- readPNG('plot1.png')
plot2 <- readPNG('plot2.png')

grid.arrange(rasterGrob(plot1),rasterGrob(plot2),ncol=1)
```

Alternative: If you want to save the plot using ggsave, instead of grid.arrange you can use

```
tmp <- arrangeGrob(rasterGrob(plot1),rasterGrob(plot2),ncol=1)
ggsave('filename.png',tmp,width=12,height=5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what your concern is about loading all the image files -- how else could you read their data to create the new image?

ETA: to load the files, I'd just use `png::readPNG` .  One way to collect the images would be(12 images selected here)

```
filenames<-dir(pattern='compo')
foo<-list()
for(j in 1:12) foo[[j]]<-readPNG(filenames[j]
```

If you're willing to load them and use the base `plot` tools,  then `layout` is the command you want.  E.g., for 12 images loaded

```
layout(matrix(1:12,nr=4,byr=T))
for (j in 1:12) plot(foo[[j]])
```

Comment: Hi, I have a similar Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756969/creating-large-image-collage-in-r-or-python) but more than 500 images. When I attempted your answer here it break after a long wait. can you help on this ? Tried using magickr and collage image packages but did not get to what I need

Comment: @user5249203  I find it unlikely that you can generate any useful information by trying to combine 500 images.  Possibly if you open them serially, down-sample each one to maybe 10% of the original size, you could use them for a mosaic but not much else